# Unable to process multiple values in parameter

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add multiple IP address to a rule in Windows Firewall. For some reason the script I have written below is only adding one of the IP addresses I am specifying and seems to override the other.

This is the script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (

        [switch]$NormalHardening,
        [switch]$AcceptEULA,
        [switch]$AddCustomPort,
        [IPAddress[]]$AdditionalPorts
)

foreach ($Port in $AdditionalPorts)  
{ 
    Write-Host "Additional Ports added were: $Port"
    Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "HTTP" | Set-NetFirewallRule -RemoteAddress "10.0.0.0/8","172.16.0.0/12","192.168.0.0/16",$Port
}
```

I enter in this at the command line:

```
.\test_additonal_ports.ps1 -NormalHardening -AdditionalPorts 32.25.48.97, 11.12.13.14
```

so, I want two IPs to be added...however, it only adds one of them.

Results I get is this:

[image]

However, in Windows Firewall it only shows ONE of the IPs added...any ideas how I can add in both?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement sets the HTTP rule with every iteration, so your loop sets the address list

```
10.0.0.0/8
172.16.0.0/12
192.168.0.0/16
32.25.48.97
```

in the first iteration, and then replaces it with

```
10.0.0.0/8
172.16.0.0/12
192.168.0.0/16
11.12.13.14
```

in the second iteration.

Build a complete list of the IP addresses you want in that rule, then update the rule once.

```
$addr = '10.0.0.0/8', '172.16.0.0/12', '192.168.0.0/16'
$addr += $AdditionalPorts

Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName 'HTTP' | Set-NetFirewallRule -RemoteAddress $addr
```

BTW, you shouldn't name the parameter `$AdditionalPorts`. [IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) and [ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29) are entirely different things, so don't confuse them. A parameter name `$AdditionalAddresses` or `$AdditionalIPRanges` would be more appropriate.

Comment: thanks for that..works perfectly. I was actually going to change the name anyway as initially it was designed to add additional ports...then changed to addresses.